# chrome copy paste of URL with german umlaut changes characters

Tags: google-chrome, security, url, vulnerabilities

I am using chrome 41 on Windows 7 (classic theme).
In chrome i have this url `http://www.faszinationtür.de/images/PDFs/prospekt49.pdf` open and copied it to the clipboard the result is the following `http://www.xn--faszinationtr-7ob.de/images/PDFs/prospekt49.pdf`

```
// why does this 
http://www.faszinationtür.de/images/PDFs/prospekt49.pdf
// is copied / pasted as this
http://www.xn--faszinationtr-7ob.de/images/PDFs/prospekt49.pdf
```

Is this some strange URL-Rewriting according to a standard, or some javascript magic to rewrite the URL in the address bar or is my computer hacked?

#### Update to add details to the given answer

From [RFC3492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492)

```
Punycode is a simple and efficient transfer encoding syntax designed
for use with Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA).
It uniquely and reversibly transforms a Unicode string into an ASCII
string.  ASCII characters in the Unicode string are represented
literally, and non-ASCII characters are represented by ASCII
characters that are allowed in host name labels (letters, digits, and
hyphens).  This document defines a general algorithm called
Bootstring that allows a string of basic code points to uniquely
represent any string of code points drawn from a larger set.
Punycode is an instance of Bootstring that uses particular parameter
values specified by this document, appropriate for IDNA.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [ASCII Compatible Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode). Use [Punycode Converter](http://www.charset.org/punycode.php) to confirm that these two addresses correspond with each other.